# jQuery a href and button

Tags: jquery

It's easy to say that `<a href>` and a button can have the same functions, but it's not working.

This is the sample link of my website: http://cocopop12.site11.com/search/.
It's a YouTube plugin that has 2 buttons on the right side, Preview and Select.

The problem is that if you click preview it should play the YouTube video. But it's not working. The code is below.

This is the link (the link is working, I just copy this on the thumbnails):

```
<a class="videoThumb4" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $yValue['videoid'] . '">
' . $yValue['description'] . '
</a>
```

This is the button which I want to replace on hover.

```
<input class="videoThumb4" onClick="location.href=\'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $yValue['videoid'] . '\'" type="button" name="previewSel" value="Preview" id="previewbut">
```

The jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
<!-- videoThumb is a css class found in the foreach list class="videoThumb". ytvideo is the holder ID set as div ID-->
$(".videoThumb4").ytplaylist({
    holderId: 'ytvideo4',
    html5: true,
    playerWidth: '520',
    autoPlay: false,
    sliding: false,
    listsliding: true,
    social: true,
    autoHide: false,
    playfirst: 0,
    playOnLoad: false,
    modestbranding: true,
    showInfo: false
});
});


// HOVER
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[type=button]#previewbut, #selectbut").hide();
$("li#static").hover(
function() {
    $(this).find('#previewbut, #selectbut').fadeIn();
},
function() {
    $(this).find('#previewbut, #selectbut').fadeOut();
});
});
```

The full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Youtube Search</title>
<meta name="description" content="youtube keyword playlist jquery and php Gdata Api version2" />
<meta name="copyright" content="www.cfconsultancy.nl" />
<meta name="web_author" content="Ceasar Feijen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/index.css" />
<!-- Remove all above if you are including this file -->

<!-- Needed for the youtube player -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/youtubeplaylist.css" />

<!-- Example css playlist to the right. See example 3 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/youtubeplaylist-right-with-thumbs.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.youtubeplaylist-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">     
        $(function() {
            <!-- videoThumb is a css class found in the foreach list class="videoThumb". ytvideo is the holder ID set as div ID-->
            $(".videoThumb4").ytplaylist({
                holderId: 'ytvideo4',
                html5: true,
                playerWidth: '520',
                autoPlay: false,
                sliding: false,
                listsliding: true,
                social: true,
                autoHide: false,
                playfirst: 0,
                playOnLoad: false,
                modestbranding: true,
                showInfo: false
            });
        });


        // HOVER
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input[type=button]#previewbut, #selectbut").hide();
            $("li#static").hover(
            function() {
                $(this).find('#previewbut, #selectbut').fadeIn();
            },
            function() {
                $(this).find('#previewbut, #selectbut').fadeOut();
            });
        });


</script>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <style>
    /************** Code for Demo **************/

    /* Containing Element */
    /* Static Image Shown Before Hover */
    a#static{
      z-index:1;
        }
    input[type=button]#previewbut {
        background-color: #9B9B9B;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration:none;
        border:0px;
        width:100px;

    }

    input[type=button]#previewbut {
        position: absolute;
        margin-top:-45px;
        margin-left:50px;

        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 11px;
        padding: 10px 5px;
        text-decoration: none;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #5C5C5C;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #5C5C5C;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #5C5C5C;

    }
    input[type=button]#previewbut:hover {
        background-color: #007073;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    input[type=button]#selectbut {
        background-color: #9B9B9B;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration:none;
        border:0px;
    }

    input[type=button]#selectbut {
        position: absolute;
        margin-top:-45px;
        margin-left:170px;
        width:100px;

        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 11px;
        padding: 10px 5px;
        text-decoration: none;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #5C5C5C;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #5C5C5C;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #5C5C5C;

    }
    input[type=button]#selectbut:hover {
        background-color: #007073;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

<!-- Needed for the youtube player example 3 -->
<div class="youtubeplayer">
    <?php
    //if ( !isset( $_POST['subKW'] ) ) {
    ?>
    <h2>Search</h2>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ); ?>">
        Input keyword : <input type="text" name="kw" value=""> <br />
        <input type="submit" name="subKW" value="Search">
    </form>
    <?php
    //} else {
    ?>
    <h2>YT Playlist  <a href="index.php">Back</a></h2><!-- END  -->
    <div class="yt_holder yt_holder_right">
        <div id="ytvideo4"></div>
            <!--Up and Down arrow -->
            <div class="you_up"><img src="css/up_arrow.png" alt="+ Slide" title="HIDE" /></div>
            <div class="you_down"><img src="css/down_arrow.png" alt="- Slide" title="SHOW" /></div>
            <!-- END  -->
            <div class="youplayer ytplayerright">
            <ul class="videoyou videoytright">
            <?php
            //$kw = $_POST['kw'];
            //global $kw;
            // Use like this.
            include_once('class/class.youtubelist.php');
            //in this example a playlist
            //$video = new youtubelist('playlist');
            //Keywords
            $video = new youtubelist('keywords');
            $video->set_keywords( /*$kw*/ 'yoga' );         
            //This is the link to the playlist.
            //http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAEAD0FC99564BA7F
            //REMOVE the PL from the string if there is an PL after list=
            $video->set_playlist('AEAD0FC99564BA7F');
            $video->set_max(50);
            $video->set_order('none'); // to retrieve most actual video's
            $video->set_cachexml(false);
            $video->set_cachelife(86400);
            $video->set_xmlpath('./cache/');
            $video->set_start(1);
            // --Set text and description length
            $video->set_descriptionlength(85);
            $video->set_titlelength(25);

            if ( $video->get_videos() !=null ) {
                foreach ($video->get_videos() as $yKey => $yValue) {
                    echo '
                    <li id="static">
                        <p>' . $yValue['title'] . '</p>
                        <span class="time timeright">' . $yValue['time'] . '</span>

                        <a class="videoThumb4" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $yValue['videoid'] . '">
                            ' . $yValue['description'] . '
                        </a>
                        <!--<a class="videoThumb4" id="previewbut" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $yValue['videoid'] . '">
                            Preview
                        </a>-->

                        <a class="videoThumb4" id="previewbut" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $yValue['videoid'] . '">
                            Preview
                        </a>

                        <!--<input class="videoThumb4" onClick="location.href=\'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $yValue['videoid'] . '\'" type="button" name="previewSel" value="Preview" id="previewbut">-->

                        <input class="videoThumb4" type="button" name="selectSel" value="Select" id="selectbut">
                    </li>                   
                    ';
                }
            }else{
                echo '<li>Sorry, no video\'s found</li>';
            }
            ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Remove if you don't want the footer shadow -->
        <div style="height:0px; font-size:0em;clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="ytfooter ytfooterright">&nbsp;</div>
        <!-- END -->
    </div>

    <?php
    //}
    ?>

</div>
<!-- END youtube player -->


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In not too familiar with this youtube plugin... But does the `.ytplaylist()` function handle the click event as well?  Perhaps you need to place that code within an `.on('click')` handler...

Comment: Please show the generated HTML, not the PHP code.

Comment: huh -1 Not Fair.. Downvoters should comment why they downvoted thats how people learn while posting questions : For me the question looks ok with code and explanation..

Comment: Man that's a lot of code you've posted. Please limit it to only the code that is pertinent to the question.

Comment: im so sorry this is my first time. so .on('click') it will get the same value from the href?

Comment: i try this but its not working

    $('.videoThumb4').on('click', '#previewbut', function() {
    $(".videoThumb4").ytplaylist({
     holderId: 'ytvideo4',
     html5: true,
     playerWidth: '520',
     autoPlay: false,
     sliding: false,
     listsliding: true,
     social: true,
     autoHide: false,
     playfirst: 0,
     playOnLoad: false,
     modestbranding: true,
     showInfo: false
    });
    });

is that correct code?

Comment: @user1506189 No. That code is not correct. You are attempting to delegate a function to an item that is dynamically loaded. You need to pick a `static parent element` to bind that function to. Based on your code, it looks like `$('.yt_holder').on('click', '.videoThumb4', function(){ });` would be the best method to delegate for you. However, I'm not sure if this will work.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thank you thank you so much for your reply it helps me a lot. Now when i click the button it plays. But there is a problem it only play the first one on the list but not each of it. pls see the link i provide. http://cocopop12.site11.com/search/index.php